# How to fix ' ' around elements in an array after reading from file

Tags: python

I'm reading in a txt file that looks something like this:

```
2
3
72 17
44 23
31 24
1
26
```

After reading it and stripping the newlines I get this:

```
['2', '3', '72 17', '44 23', '31 24', '1', '26']
```

This is fine but when I want to pass this array into my function it either throws errors or won't take the values out correctly.

I want to know how to read in my file like this instead:

```
[2, 3, 72 17, 44 23, 31 24, 1, 26]
```

If I can't do that (probably because of the double numbers without a comma?), then is there a different way to pass this to my function besides just saying `def functionA(nums):`?

```
with open("shoppingTest.txt") as f:
    nums = f.readlines()
nums = [x.strip() for x in nums]
print nums
```

Comment: What is the type of `72 17`? Is it a `int` or `str`?

Comment: Be clear about a few things. Do you want numbers as strings or integers? Do you want your double numbers combined or separate?

Comment: Also,what's the error?

Comment: i dont think it can be read as integar with a space in between

Comment: `44 23` makes no sense. When a list is printed, all the elements are separated by comma. If `44` and `23` are in the same element, it can't be a number, it has to be a string.

Comment: @BlackBeard I need both numbers [72 17] to be separate because I am using them separately but I read them in together since they are on the same line.

Comment: Do you want `[2, 3, [72, 17], ...]? That would make more sense.

Comment: @Barmar if the rest of my elements I read in are ints though do I need to make the whole array strings?

Comment: @Barmar yes, `[2, 3, [72, 17], ...]` I think would be fine as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple,

```
file = open("shoppingTest.txt")
print [int(item) for item in file.read().split()]
```

Comment: That will produce `["2", "3", ["72", "17"], ...]`

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert strings (text) into integers. You can just do this with `int(x)`.

You could also use `split` again and some list comprehensions to deal with the doubles:

```
orig = ['2', '3', '72 17', '44 23', '31 24', '1', '26']
resplit = [x.split() for x in orig]
flat = [item for sublist in resplit for item in sublist]

as_ints = [int(x) for x in a]
as_ints
> [2, 3, 72, 17, 44, 23, 31, 24, 1, 26]
```

Comment: I think this solution is even better than what I had originally wanted and will make the rest of my program easier, so yes this works!

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark with a green check if the issue is solved :)

Comment: @Mel In the comment above you said you wanted `[72, 17]` in a nested list, to reflect that they were in the same line in the file. Now you don't care about the line boundaries?

Comment: @Barmar yes I said a solution with the nested list would be fine as well but having them all converted to single ints is ideally what was best

Comment: @Mel You said the problem was that you're passing the list into another function. So it really depends on what that function is expecting, unless you can also change that function to match this format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `int()` to convert the strings to integers. And if the line contains multiple numbers, you have to first split it, and then call `int()` on those substrings.

```
result = []
for x in nums:
    x = x.strip()
    if " " in x:
        result.append(map(int, x.split(" ")))
    else:
        result.append(int(x))
print(result)
```